# detect if point inside a polygon when point lies in the horizontal of external segment

Tags: c++, algorithm

Im trying to detect if an arbitrary polygon is inside another or not. 
It works almost perfectly on almost every shape, but found a case I don¡t know how to resolve.

I have the polygons defined by vertices. 
To check if one polygon is inside the other, I cycle the vertex and check if any of it is outside the "contour" shape. To check if a point lies inside the hull of the contour, I cast a "ray" from it towards positive X and check how many segments of the "contour" I collide.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule

I have into account the problem of horizontal segments.

> Most implementations of the ray casting algorithm consecutively check intersections of a ray with  all sides of the polygon in turn. In this case the following problem must be addressed. 
>   If the ray  passes exactly through a vertex of a polygon, then it will intersect 2 segments at their endpoints.  While it is OK for the case of the topmost vertex in the example or the vertex between crossing 4 and  5, the case of the rightmost vertex (in the example) requires that we count one intersection for the  algorithm to work correctly. A similar problem arises with horizontal segments that happen to fall  on the ray. The issue is solved as follows: If the intersection point is a vertex of a tested polygon side, then the intersection counts only if the second vertex of the side lies below the ray. This is  effectively equivalent to considering vertices on the ray as lying slightly above the ray.

The problem became when I tried to check 2 identical boxes, perfectly aligned, width same height (for sake of precision, the '"' glyph on Arial Typeface.

All of the vertex of any of the boxes will collide with the horizontal of the other, and renders me unable to check if it is inside or outside. If I check if it is horizontal, and wheter or not lies left to the tested point, It works, but then the "#" glyph will give a false positive on his inner contour.

There is my algorithm:

```
bool GRPOBJECTBUILDER::CheckPointInsideContour(GRPPOINT testedpoint, GRPSPLINE* processedspline)
{
bool        isinside = false;
XDWORD  i;
XDWORD  j;

for(i=0, j = processedspline->points.GetSize()-2; i < processedspline->points.GetSize()-1; j = i++)
    {
        GRPANCHORPOINT* splinepointi = processedspline->points.Get(i);
        GRPANCHORPOINT* splinepointj = processedspline->points.Get(j);

            if (testedpoint.y == splinepointi->value.y == splinepointj->value.y) //es un segmento horizontal y estamos en el espacio
            {
                if ((splinepointi->value.x>splinepointj->value.x && testedpoint.x>splinepointi->value.x) || 
                        (splinepointi->value.x<splinepointj->value.x && testedpoint.x<splinepointi->value.x))                       
                    return true;
            }

        bool        isbetweeny      =    (splinepointi->value.y > testedpoint.y && splinepointj->value.y < testedpoint.y) || 
                                                         (splinepointi->value.y < testedpoint.y && splinepointj->value.y > testedpoint.y);

            if ((testedpoint.y == splinepointi->value.y) && (splinepointi->value.y!=splinepointj->value.y)) //check con vertice                 
                    isbetweeny=true;

        GLFLOAT m = 0.0f;

        if((splinepointi->value.y - splinepointj->value.y) != 0.0f)
                    m = (splinepointi->value.x - splinepointj->value.x) / (splinepointi->value.y - splinepointj->value.y);
            else  
                        m = 0;      

        bool islefttox  = (testedpoint.x <= ((m*(testedpoint.y - splinepointj->value.y)) + splinepointj->value.x));

        if(isbetweeny && islefttox) 
            isinside = !isinside;                           
}

if (isinside)
    return true;
return false;
}
```

Is there something I should check that Im forgotting?

Thanks.

Comment: "To check if one polygon is inside the other, I cycle the vertex and check if any of it is outside the "contour" shape." — I'm not sure I followed this. You consider polygon A to be _inside_ polygon B if any vertex of A lies _outside_ B?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I cycle the polygon vertex and return false if any vertex of A lies outside (for speed).

Comment: So you've separately, and completely unrelated to the question, got a problem e.g. if the + symbol were a horizontal rect and a separate vertical rect? You'd conclude they were not overlapping? Not that it matters. Apologies for the gross digression.

Comment: no no, as the question says, the problem appears when I check if a point (wich lies collinear to a external horizontal segment of the convex shape) is inside or outside the poly. The odd-rule hits 3 segments (cause the ray hits 2 vertices, it counts as hitting 3 segments, and therefore it thinks is an "inner" poly with a false positive).

Comment: Yes, I understand that my query is unrelated to the question. But what I'm getting at (albeit initially unwittingly) is whether the edge case you're hitting might equally be considered as being on the boundary between those cases where "any point inside" works as a polygon overlap test and those cases where it doesn't. If you imagine the example of the +, that overlap test doesn't work immediately but if you slowly squash, say, the vertical rectangle vertically then the crossover point when the test starts working is where its vertices head inside the horizontal box.